# Not reaching index.jsp in spring java app

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, web

I am having a problem reaching the index.jsp file in a java web application.

The folder screenshot:

[image]

I can only reach the index.jsp file below /webapp/ folder. I have another index.jsp into WEB-INF folder but I can´t reach it.

The app is a Java one with Spring, Hibernate, ...
Spring is configured using java classes instead xml files.

[image]

[image]

Into WEB-INF/vista folder there is another index.jsp and I can´t reach it.
Do you know what´s wrong with the configuration files?

Thanks.

Comment: change `viewResolver.setPrefix(..` to `"/WEB-INF/"`. also you may have to keep your static resources in `/resources` folder

Comment: I tried it and it doesn´t work. I have three different index.jsp at the same time in this locations: /webbapp , /WEB-INF/ and /WEB-INF/vista and always is launched the one in /webapp

Comment: run application with debug logs and verify if welcome pages are accepted by spring mvc

Comment: The index.jsp file at /webapp is launched, so I suppose they are accepted. I have an html file there but I am not using it.

Comment: Whatever I write in setPrefix() doesn´t make any effect, it always runs webapp/index.jsp